# Using nested NSPredicate SUBQUERY

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

This is the relevant part of my object graph:

```
Store <-->> Gift <<--> Person <<-->> Tag
```

I'd like to be able to filter the stores by the tag.filtering attribute, like this:

```
ANY gifts.person.tags.filtering == YES
```

But I understand why this doesn't work, due to the restriction to one to-many keys. So I am trying to use a set of nested SUBQUERY predicates, like this:

```
NSPredicate* filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"(0 != SUBQUERY(gifts, $x, 
     (0 != SUBQUERY($x.person.tags, $y, $y.filtering==YES).@count)).@count)"];
```

This fails at runtime with an error:

```
"SQLite error code:1, 'no such column: t3.ZFILTERING'"
```

It seems like I'm on the right track, here, but can't find any other examples that use the same syntax. What am I missing?

Comment: I cannot see an obvious error. Can you try `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(gifts, $x, ANY $x.person.tags.filtering == YES).@count != 0"]` instead? This should do the same but is slightly simpler.

Comment: Yes, that's working. I guess I was overthinking things. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From my comment above:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SUBQUERY(gifts, $x, ANY $x.person.tags.filtering == YES).@count != 0"]
```

works, and is even simpler than a nested SUBQUERY.